# OpenAm with Tivoly Directory Server

Tags: ldap, openam

Am testing OpenAm 12 (yeah am pretty new to this) and am trying to set an Tivoli Directory Server as Datasource with little success.

My settings seem ok (i've test my binding using JXplorer) but am getting this error :

```
ERROR: Connection factory became offline: CachedConnectionPool(size=0[in:0
+out:0 + pending:0],maxSize=10, blocked=0,
factory=AuthenticatedConnectionFactory(HeartBeatConnectionFactory(LDAPConnection
Factory(MYHOST:PORT)), SimpleBindRequest(name=cn=admin, authentication=simple, controls=[])))
```

where **HOST:PORT** are correctly set.

Full debug stack goes like :

```
amIdm:06/17/2015 02:58:20:158 PM CEST: Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-4,5,main]
IdRepoPluginsCache.getIdRepoPlugins orgName: dc=openam,dc=example,dc=com
DJLDAPv3Repo:06/17/2015 02:58:20:159 PM CEST: Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-4,5,main]
getSupportedTypes invoked
amIdm:06/17/2015 02:58:20:159 PM CEST: Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-4,5,main]
IdRepoPluginsCache.getIdRepoPlugins orgName: dc=openam,dc=example,dc=com
DJLDAPv3Repo:06/17/2015 02:58:20:159 PM CEST: Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-4,5,main]
getSupportedTypes invoked
amIdm:06/17/2015 02:58:20:159 PM CEST: Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-4,5,main]
IdRepoPluginsCache.getIdRepoPlugins orgName: dc=openam,dc=example,dc=com
DJLDAPv3Repo:06/17/2015 02:58:20:159 PM CEST: Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-4,5,main]
getSupportedTypes invoked
amIdm:06/17/2015 02:58:20:160 PM CEST: Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-4,5,main]
IdRepoPluginsCache.getIdRepoPlugins orgName: dc=openam,dc=example,dc=com
DJLDAPv3Repo:06/17/2015 02:58:20:160 PM CEST: Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-4,5,main]
getSupportedTypes invoked
amIdm:06/17/2015 02:58:20:160 PM CEST: Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-4,5,main]
IdRepoPluginsCache.getIdRepoPlugins orgName: dc=openam,dc=example,dc=com
DJLDAPv3Repo:06/17/2015 02:58:20:160 PM CEST: Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-4,5,main]
getSupportedTypes invoked
amIdm:06/17/2015 02:58:20:160 PM CEST: Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-4,5,main]
IdRepoPluginsCache.getIdRepoPlugins orgName: dc=openam,dc=example,dc=com
DJLDAPv3Repo:06/17/2015 02:58:20:160 PM CEST: Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-4,5,main]
getSupportedTypes invoked
amIdm:06/17/2015 02:58:20:164 PM CEST: Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-4,5,main]
IdRepoPluginsCache.getIdRepoPlugins orgName: dc=openam,dc=example,dc=com
DJLDAPv3Repo:06/17/2015 02:58:20:164 PM CEST: Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-4,5,main]
getSupportedTypes invoked
amIdm:06/17/2015 02:58:20:175 PM CEST: Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-4,5,main]
IdRepoPluginsCache.getIdRepoPlugins for OrgName: dc=openam,dc=example,dc=com Op: Operation: service Type: IdType: realm
DJLDAPv3Repo:06/17/2015 02:58:20:175 PM CEST: Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-4,5,main]
getAssignedServices invoked
DJLDAPv3Repo:06/17/2015 02:58:20:175 PM CEST: Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-4,5,main]
Assigned services returned: []
amIdm:06/17/2015 02:58:20:176 PM CEST: Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-4,5,main]
IdRepoPluginsCache.getIdRepoPlugins for OrgName: dc=openam,dc=example,dc=com Op: Operation: read Type: IdType: user
amIdm:06/17/2015 02:58:20:176 PM CEST: Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-4,5,main]
IdRepoPluginsCache.getIdRepoPlugins orgName: dc=openam,dc=example,dc=com
DJLDAPv3Repo:06/17/2015 02:58:20:176 PM CEST: Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-4,5,main]
getSupportedTypes invoked
DJLDAPv3Repo:06/17/2015 02:58:20:176 PM CEST: Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-4,5,main]
getSupportedOperations invoked
amIdm:06/17/2015 02:58:20:176 PM CEST: Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-4,5,main]
IdRepoPluginsCache.getIdRepoPlugins retuned for OrgName: dc=openam,dc=example,dc=com Op: Operation: read Type: IdType: user Plugins: [org.forgerock.openam.idrepo.ldap.DJLDAPv3Repo, com.sun.identity.idm.plugins.internal.SpecialRepo]
DJLDAPv3Repo:06/17/2015 02:58:20:177 PM CEST: Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-4,5,main]
search invoked with type: IdType: user pattern: * avPairs: null maxTime: 5 maxResults: 100 returnAttrs: null returnAllAttrs: false filterOp: 0 recursive: false
LDAPUtils:06/17/2015 02:58:20:212 PM CEST: Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-4,5,main]
ERROR: Connection factory became offline: CachedConnectionPool(size=0[in:0 + out:0 + pending:0], maxSize=10, blocked=0, factory=AuthenticatedConnectionFactory(HeartBeatConnectionFactory(LDAPConnectionFactory(MYHOST:PORT)), SimpleBindRequest(name=cn=admin, authentication=simple, controls=[])))
org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.ConnectionException: Server Connection Closed
    at org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.ErrorResultException.newErrorResult(ErrorResultException.java:210)
    at com.forgerock.opendj.ldap.AbstractLDAPFutureResultImpl.setResultOrError(AbstractLDAPFutureResultImpl.java:138)
    at com.forgerock.opendj.ldap.AbstractLDAPFutureResultImpl.adaptErrorResult(AbstractLDAPFutureResultImpl.java:127)
    at com.forgerock.opendj.ldap.LDAPConnection.close(LDAPConnection.java:690)
    at com.forgerock.opendj.ldap.LDAPClientFilter.handleClose(LDAPClientFilter.java:480)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$4.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:76)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:550)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.NIOConnection.preClose(NIOConnection.java:744)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOConnection.preClose(TCPNIOConnection.java:97)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.NIOConnection.close0(NIOConnection.java:475)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOConnection.close0(TCPNIOConnection.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.read(TCPNIOTransport.java:623)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTemporarySelectorReader.readNow0(TCPNIOTemporarySelectorReader.java:65)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.tmpselectors.TemporarySelectorReader.read0(TemporarySelectorReader.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.tmpselectors.TemporarySelectorReader.read0(TemporarySelectorReader.java:141)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.tmpselectors.TemporarySelectorReader.read(TemporarySelectorReader.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.tmpselectors.TemporarySelectorReader.read(TemporarySelectorReader.java:75)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.AbstractReader.read(AbstractReader.java:72)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransportFilter.handleRead(TCPNIOTransportFilter.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.TransportFilter.handleRead(TransportFilter.java:173)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:550)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

DJLDAPv3Repo:06/17/2015 02:58:20:212 PM CEST: Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-4,5,main]
ERROR: Unexpected error occurred during search
org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.ConnectionException: Connect Error: No operational connection factories available
    at org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.ErrorResultException.newErrorResult(ErrorResultException.java:210)
    at org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.ErrorResultException.newErrorResult(ErrorResultException.java:172)
    at org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.ErrorResultException.newErrorResult(ErrorResultException.java:142)
    at org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.AbstractLoadBalancingAlgorithm.getMonitoredConnectionFactory(AbstractLoadBalancingAlgorithm.java:389)
    at org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.AbstractLoadBalancingAlgorithm.access$100(AbstractLoadBalancingAlgorithm.java:55)
    at org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.AbstractLoadBalancingAlgorithm$MonitoredConnectionFactory.getConnection(AbstractLoadBalancingAlgorithm.java:84)
    at org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.LoadBalancer.getConnection(LoadBalancer.java:53)
    at org.forgerock.openam.idrepo.ldap.DJLDAPv3Repo.search(DJLDAPv3Repo.java:1124)
    at com.sun.identity.idm.server.IdServicesImpl.search(IdServicesImpl.java:1528)
    at com.sun.identity.idm.server.IdCachedServicesImpl.search(IdCachedServicesImpl.java:640)
    at com.sun.identity.idm.AMIdentityRepository.searchIdentities(AMIdentityRepository.java:298)
    at com.sun.identity.console.idm.model.EntitiesModelImpl.getEntityNames(EntitiesModelImpl.java:196)
    at com.sun.identity.console.idm.EntitiesViewBean.getEntityNames(EntitiesViewBean.java:248)
    at com.sun.identity.console.idm.EntitiesViewBean.beginDisplay(EntitiesViewBean.java:192)
    at com.iplanet.jato.taglib.UseViewBeanTag.doStartTag(UseViewBeanTag.java:149)
    at org.apache.jsp.console.idm.Entities_jsp._jspService(Entities_jsp.java:143)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
    at com.iplanet.jato.view.ViewBeanBase.forward(ViewBeanBase.java:340)
    at com.iplanet.jato.view.ViewBeanBase.forwardTo(ViewBeanBase.java:261)
    at com.sun.identity.console.base.AMViewBeanBase.forwardTo(AMViewBeanBase.java:161)
    at com.sun.identity.console.base.AMPrimaryMastHeadViewBean.forwardTo(AMPrimaryMastHeadViewBean.java:116)
    at com.sun.identity.console.idm.HomeViewBean.forwardTo(HomeViewBean.java:96)
    at com.sun.identity.console.realm.RealmPropertiesBase.nodeClicked(RealmPropertiesBase.java:77)
    at com.sun.web.ui.view.tabs.CCTabs.handleTabHrefRequest(CCTabs.java:129)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.iplanet.jato.view.command.DefaultRequestHandlingCommand.execute(DefaultRequestHandlingCommand.java:183)
    at com.iplanet.jato.view.RequestHandlingViewBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlingViewBase.java:308)
    at com.iplanet.jato.view.ViewBeanBase.dispatchInvocation(ViewBeanBase.java:802)
    at com.iplanet.jato.view.ViewBeanBase.invokeRequestHandlerInternal(ViewBeanBase.java:740)
    at com.iplanet.jato.view.ViewBeanBase.invokeRequestHandlerInternal(ViewBeanBase.java:760)
    at com.iplanet.jato.view.ViewBeanBase.invokeRequestHandler(ViewBeanBase.java:571)
    at com.iplanet.jato.ApplicationServletBase.dispatchRequest(ApplicationServletBase.java:957)
    at com.iplanet.jato.ApplicationServletBase.processRequest(ApplicationServletBase.java:615)
    at com.iplanet.jato.ApplicationServletBase.doGet(ApplicationServletBase.java:459)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.forgerock.openam.validation.ResponseValidationFilter.doFilter(ResponseValidationFilter.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.sun.identity.setup.AMSetupFilter.doFilter(AMSetupFilter.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.ConnectionException: Server Connection Closed
    at org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.ErrorResultException.newErrorResult(ErrorResultException.java:210)
    at com.forgerock.opendj.ldap.AbstractLDAPFutureResultImpl.setResultOrError(AbstractLDAPFutureResultImpl.java:138)
    at com.forgerock.opendj.ldap.AbstractLDAPFutureResultImpl.adaptErrorResult(AbstractLDAPFutureResultImpl.java:127)
    at com.forgerock.opendj.ldap.LDAPConnection.close(LDAPConnection.java:690)
    at com.forgerock.opendj.ldap.LDAPClientFilter.handleClose(LDAPClientFilter.java:480)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$4.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:76)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:550)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.NIOConnection.preClose(NIOConnection.java:744)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOConnection.preClose(TCPNIOConnection.java:97)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.NIOConnection.close0(NIOConnection.java:475)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOConnection.close0(TCPNIOConnection.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.read(TCPNIOTransport.java:623)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTemporarySelectorReader.readNow0(TCPNIOTemporarySelectorReader.java:65)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.tmpselectors.TemporarySelectorReader.read0(TemporarySelectorReader.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.tmpselectors.TemporarySelectorReader.read0(TemporarySelectorReader.java:141)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.tmpselectors.TemporarySelectorReader.read(TemporarySelectorReader.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.tmpselectors.TemporarySelectorReader.read(TemporarySelectorReader.java:75)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.AbstractReader.read(AbstractReader.java:72)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransportFilter.handleRead(TCPNIOTransportFilter.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.TransportFilter.handleRead(TransportFilter.java:173)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:550)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    ... 1 more
```

If someone can help me with this i'll appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this error comes from the fact that my LDAP directory doesn't acept annonymous connections. When annonymous is enable everything works just as intended but this is not a acceptable solution when i'll deploy on production.

I guess the heartbeat done by the pluggin `org.forgerock.openam.idrepo.ldap.DJLDAPv3Repo` doesn't try to use the provided "admin" credentials but does use them for the search.

Using the pluggin `com.sun.identity.idm.plugins.ldapv3.LDAPv3Repo` lets me connect to my LDAP directory but i get other kind of errors when using OpenAm authentication so it's not really a solution.

**------------ Edit ------------**

The solution was given to me by a member of OpenAm forums. I had to turn off the LDAP heartbeat requests by setting `openam-auth-ldap-heartbeat-interval` to 0.

For more info see https://forgerock.org/topic/tivoli-ldap-with-annonymous-connection-disabled/#post-4520

**------------------------------**